# VB.NET How to set the sender when generating a mail via Outlook

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I would know if there is a way to set the address of the sender of a mail in vb.net.
For example, if I want to send a mail with my address: "my.address@mail.com" I would have something like this:

```
 objMail = objOutlk.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'Email   item
        objMail.From = "my.address@mail.com" 
        objMail.To = "anaddress@mail.com"
        objMail.subject = "My subject"
```

Do you know a way to do it?

Comment: What library/nuget-packet are you using? Can you not use MailMessage-class?

Comment: I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. I have to open Outlook and let the users edit their mails via Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, MailItem object in OOM does **not** expose `From` property - your code above won't even run.

If you are sending through an account POP3/SMTP configured in Outlook, set the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property. Account object can be retreiv3ed from the `Namespace.Accounts` collection.

If you are sending on behalf of another Exchange mailbox, set the `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property.

Comment: Yes, I Know MailItem.From won't work, Thank you, I will try what you say.

Answer (score 0):

Only my opinion, please dont take this as a must! It may be easier for you to use SMTP to send emails. You can send from any mailbox (that you know the credentials for) and create the 'From' name as you wish too. So you could say create an email from my.address@mail.com, with it displaying 'Chicken' when it is sent. Its pretty simple code once you get into it, and there are many better tricks you can use than the interop.outlook.

Just googled and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_send_email.htm seems helpfull

I can post you some of my code if you need any more, but sure this should give you a good heads up! :)

Hth
Chicken